# KDE hangs after login if rebooting from Windows in a dual-boot computer

Tags: dual-boot, login, kde

I run a dual-boot computer with(Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04, over which I have installed KDE 4.13.3.

After booting on Windows, the first time I try to log in to KDE, KDE hangs on splash window after KDM login.

If I restart the computer and try to log in to KDE again, it doesn't hang anymore, until I boot on Windows again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have "UTC=yes" on the file /etc/default/rcS.

When you log in to KDE, it sets the KDE time to the correct local time, and changes the BIOS time to the UTC time. When you log in to Windows, it sets Windows time to the correct local time, and changes the BIOS time to the local time.

For some reason, the first time you log in to KDE, having the local time (instead of the UTC time) on the BIOS make KDE hang. However, this boot on Ubuntu (and/or log in to KDE) is enough to change the BIOS time back to the local time. Then, if you restart the computer and try to log in to KDE again, you don't have the problem anymore.

I can't tell why having the BIOS time set to local time make KDE hang, but here is a solution:

- make Ubuntu/KDE interpret BIOS time the same way that Windows does: it should be set to local time. To do this, edit the file  /etc/default/rcS and replace "UTC=yes" by "UTC=no".

This solution worked for me (in fact, the question was just a way of sharing the solution found), but bear in mind that I have tried it during Daylight Saving Time (DST) from a place where the local time is UTC+0 when we are not in DST. Since I have not tried it outside the DST period, I am not sure I did correctly by interpreting the times as "local" and "UTC". Maybe they should be interpreted as "local with DST" and "local without DST". In this case, the solution would not be valid all around the world in every moment of the year. Please comment about it if you can.